# Sharepoint 2013 - None ULS Log anymore

Tags: logging, sharepoint-2013, uls

I encounter a strange behavior on my Sharepoint 2013 On Premise: no ULS Log are generating anymore !

Of course, I already checked the issue on the web, but any of the responses I found worked for me:

1) I have 18 Go of free space (so, enough) on the C: drive where the logs are normally stored in the log folder (the default one): 
[image: Sharepoint 2013 Log Folder]

2) I tried to change the log folder back and forth, it didn't do anything.

Is anyone encountered the same issue ? What I'm missing there ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooo, I found the answer, it was pretty dumb finally and obvious from a point of view.

The Tracing Service on the Windows Services was running on Local Service account. Whereas that same account was not present in the user group Performance Log Users on the server. Which contains some administration Sharepoint accounts.

So, I preferred to change the Local Service account on the Tracing Service by one of the Sharepoint accounts mentioned above, reboot that service and, the logs have started to run again !

For anyone encountering the same issue, here is the link that helped me: [Logging User Account](http://pwconsultant.blogspot.fr/2012/12/problem-current-sharepoint-2010farm-on.html)